# capture UITextView.text on Chinese IME

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I'm developing a app for Chinese market.
Now I have a view just simple use a UITextView that receives input text typed by user.
To observe value-change event trigged by each character user typed,I implement the following
delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView 
     shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range 
     replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

this method will be called normally when the user use other languages' IME except Chinese。
the problem is that when I pressed the [return(确认)] key ,this delegate method cannot be invoked 
normally,That is I can't get the whole NSString value typed by the user,may be for the Chinese 
Character Set is different from other IMEs.

The question is ,how does make this method can be called if the user pressed the [return] key using Chinese IME.
I test English IME,Japanese IME,these IMEs are work normally. Only the behavior of Chinese 
IME not work well as my expectation.